# Issue with transforming Pandas code to Pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I need some help in transforming my Pandas code to PySpark.
I am very new to PySpark and facing issues with this transformation.

I have weekly sales data of items sold within multiple stores.
Initial data looks like this :

| store_id | item_id | week | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-01 | 3 |
| store1 | item2 | 2021-01 | 2 |
| store2 | item1 | 2021-01 | 10 |
| store2 | item3 | 2021-01 | 1 |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-02 | 5 |
| store1 | item2 | 2021-02 | 1 |
| store2 | item1 | 2021-02 | 11 |
| store1 | item3 | 2021-03 | 6 |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-04 | 7 |
| store2 | item3 | 2021-04 | 2 |

**Step 1** : I want to transform this into a single entry per every (store, item) combination. I want to create separate columns of sales, for every unique entry in the week column.

Thus, I use this in Pandas which created the following Dataframe:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['store_id', 'item_id', 'week'])['sales'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.add_prefix('sales_week_')
```

| store_id | item_id | sales_week_2021-01 | sales_week_2021-02 | sales_week_2021-03 | sales_week_2021-04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 7 |
| store1 | item2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| store1 | item3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| store2 | item1 | 10 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| store2 | item3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

**Step 2** : Now if any item_id has 0 sales during the starting weeks, it probably means that the item was onboarded onto the store later, and thus we want to replace such values by nan. I use the following in pandas :

```
df2 = df2.mask(df2.cumsum(1).eq(0), np.nan)
```

So now, store1 and item3 contains `nan` entries for the first two weeks of 2021.

| store_id | item_id | sales_week_2021-01 | sales_week_2021-02 | sales_week_2021-03 | sales_week_2021-04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 7 |
| store1 | item2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| store1 | item3 | nan | nan | 6 | 0 |
| store2 | item1 | 10 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| store2 | item3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

### PySpark equivalent I'm trying out

**For Step 1:**

```
columns = ["store_id","item_id", "week", "sales"]
data = [("store1","item1","2021-01",3),
("store1","item2","2021-01",2),
("store2","item1","2021-01",0),
("store2","item3","2021-01",1),
("store1","item1","2021-02",5),
("store1","item2","2021-02",1),
("store2","item1","2021-02",1),
("store1","item3","2021-03",6),
("store1","item1","2021-04",7),
("store2","item3","2021-04",2)]

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(columns)

df2 = df.groupBy('store_id','item_id').pivot('week').sum('sales')

# It fills NA at all empty places by default, so :
df2=df2.na.fill(0)

#Renaming column headers:
weeks = df2.schema.names[2:]
new_weeks = [('sales_week_' + week) for week in weeks]
for i in range(0, len(weeks)):
    df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed(weeks[i], new_weeks[i])
```

**For Step 2:**
I'm stuck at this point and not sure how to achieve this transformation using PySpark. I had received inputs earlier on how do this using mask & cumsum in a pandas way : [Pandas fill NaN in columns based on some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70132755/pandas-fill-nan-in-columns-based-on-some-conditions)

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. If you want to transform a pandas dataframe to a sparkdataframe, use this: ``sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF) ``

Comment: @JAdel edited the original question, please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it done like this - The logic followed is similar to pandas code. Create a new dataframe with rowwise cumulative sum, replace values with NAN wherever cumulative-sum = 0.

Step 1 : Use RDD-map operation to get cumulative sum rows for weeks.

```
output_cols = ["store_id2", "item_id2"] + [('cumsum_week_' + week) for week in weeks]

def func1(x):
    result = []
    cur = x[2]
    result.append(cur)
    
    for i in range(1, len(weeks)):
        cur += x[i+2]
        result.append(cur)
    return (x[0],x[1],) + tuple(result)

rdd=df2.rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x))  
df3=rdd.toDF(output_cols)
```

Step 2 : Used spark sql operations to first join the two datasets, and when-otherwise clauses to apply if-else based on value 0.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

cols = list(set(df2.columns))

joindf = df2.join(df3, (df2.store_id == df3.store_id2) & (df2.item_id == df3.item_id2), "full")

for week in weeks:
    joindf = joindf.withColumn("sales_week_"+week, F.when((col("cumsum_week_"+week) > 0), col("sales_week_"+week)).otherwise(np.nan))

joindf = joindf.select(cols)
joindf.show()
```

This might not be the most optimal approach, but it worked well with huge dataset > 10 MM records, so I'm good!